# Automatically move files into correct folder on server

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator

I often need to move files from one location on a server into a set of hierarchical folders.

The filenames are usually 7 digits long - sometimes with some extra characters at the end.

The folders are set up as nested sets for each digit - 3 deep. So, a file named '6753687a.eps' for example would need be filed in the '675' folder, which is in the '67' folder, which is in the '6' folder, which is in the 'Images' folder at the root of the volume. There is no '6753' folder.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to drop groups of files into a folder or a droplet or something, and have the files automatically moved into their correct folders.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Should be possible with an apple script as a folder action. I'll see if I can whip something up later if no one else beats me to it.

Answer (score 1):

## Automator Droplet

You can do this with an Automator workflow and a script (I'm using Python, but it could be done with Bash, Applescript or anything else really).

1. Open up Automator, and choose **Application** type.
2. Add a **Run Shell Script** action to the workflow.
3. In the *Run Shell Script* action, set the *Shell* option to **`/usr/bin/python`**, and *Pass input:* to **as arguments**.
4. Set the script text to the script as shown below. Be sure to change the destination path to your desired destination.
5. **Save** the application to your desired location.

### Script

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess

destinationPath = '/Users/rob/Desktop/test'

for f in sys.argv[1:]:
    name = os.path.basename(f)
    newdir = os.path.join(destinationPath, name[:1], name[:2], name[:3])
    print newdir

    if not os.path.exists(newdir):
        os.makedirs(newdir)

    subprocess.call(['mv', f, os.path.join(newdir,name)])
#eof
```

**Important:** Change the `destinationPath =` line to the path you want (*i.e.* the folder that contains your numbered folders). Make sure to retain the single quotes around the path.

### Usage

Just drag and drop the files you want onto the application file you saved, and they'll be moved accordingly. If the proper folders don't exist already, they will be created.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that on the source locations all files are in one directory. Open Terminal, change to this directory and run

```
for i in *; do
    target="PATH/TO/Images/${i:0:1}/${i:0:2}/${i:0:3}"
    mkdir -p "$target"
    mv -v "$i" "$target"/
done
```

PS: This will probably fail if one of files in question has a name which is shorter than 3 characters.